# Setting file path location in yaml

Tags: configuration, yaml, filepath

I have three directories which are in the root directory of my machine: **yaml**, **data** and **json**.

Within my **yaml** directory I have a configuration yaml file which points to the **json** directory. Now I want to be able to get out of the **yaml** directory and then in to the **json** directory in order to point the `json_location` to this.

So far I have the following in my yaml file, but it is an absolute path. If someone else was to use my code, they would need to change the file path to meet their User profile name.

```
# configuration
config:
  json_location: /Users/jaymiee/Desktop/json/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have something that processes the yaml check the documentation for variables. For Instance on serverless they use [variables](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables) to make it dynamic, it involves using "$" but other systems use different notation:

```
# configuration
config:
  json_location: ${file(./config.json):PATH}
```

Comment: bluecombats, I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.

Comment: @Yunnosch should I provide some code from the link I mentioned to answer this question?

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: And the solution should at least be summarised directly here, while still providing the reference to what you are quoting. Linked content is not considered part of the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Option 1. Get the user's home path as a variable and store that into your config

Option 2. let your app code handle directory changes. In Python, you could do something like:

```py
from pathlib import Path
home = str(Path.home())       # python 3.5+
yaml_location = os.path.join(home, "yaml")
```